# Google Analytics track files download

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I wanna track, how often a file has been downloaded via Google Analytics.

This is the code, I include in every site:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'url');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

This is how my link looks:

```
<a href="File.zip" onclick="ga('send', 'pageview', '/File.zip');">Some text</a>
```

If the user clicks on that link, it does not work. If I copy the JavaScript and enter it manually in the console and execute it, there is no problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong
it's just that when you redirect it    -  it stops the execution of the analytics (all happens very fast)

I've already met this problem  a week ago  - and here is the solution which i've used :

(you want this : click ---> don't redirect---> goto google ----> when you return from google , re-click the element)

Add this js code:

```
$("body").on('click', '[data-ga]', function (e)
{
    var _ = $(this);
    if (_.data('prevented') == 1)
    {
        _.removeData("prevented");
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    _.data('prevented', 1);
    window.__gacb = function () { _[0].click(); };
    new Function(_.data('ga'))();
    return false;
});
```

Also -  [**use the google analytic code which provide callback**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) : (we want to trigger the click ourself after(!!!) google writes data)

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': '/my-new-page',
  'hitCallback': function() {
    window.__gacb();  <---- very important
  }
});
```

So you're code would be :

```
<a href="File.zip" data-ga="  ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'page': '/my-new-page',
      'hitCallback': function() {
        window.__gacb();  <---- very important
      }
    });"
```

explanation :

When you press on the link , you `preventDefault` it. you read the `data-ga` code . and runs it. google would get this request and run a callback which inturn  you flag to the script : "I already prevented this click , so now - don't prevent it"

so the callback that google runs , actually trigger another click - as you wanted.

Comment: p.s. i've just noticed that jQuery tag is not present. sorry for that. but you get the idea.

Comment: @Niklas check that there are no new lines - it should all be in one line. upload the code where you pasted.

Comment: It was my mistake. Copied too fast, without paying attention. This code rocks like hell! Thank you very much!

Comment: +1 but perhaps an even better solution would be to use Google Tag Manager and the "event listener" tags - specifically design for that kind of thing and great if you need to include any tags besides Google Analytics.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I used it in our site for captureing events when clicking on certain buttons which : download files ( do submit) , redirects etc... as far as i know , there is no solution for this becuase the page redirects , submit back to server **very fast** so the ajax dont have time to execute. the only solution ( which i found) is to pause ->go to google , callback - reclick. the other solution is to use another new page which is landing page. ( didn't want to do that)

Comment: Google claims that the event listeners add timeouts automatically so that the tags have time to fire (and it works for my in a number of different scenarios). Your mileage obviously varies but it might still be worth for others to try out (not that I'm trying to argue - after all the OP has a working solution).

Comment: @EikePierstorff can you pls reference a link which shows postback/submit/redirect with event tracking ?